# PHP ob_get_contents "sometimes" returns empty when it should not?

Tags: php

**Issue:** I am witnessing a random situation where ob_get_conents() returns nothing, when it SHOULD have something. Fails a few out of thousands of successes each day. Randomly.

**Basics:** I wrap a specific HTML generation output into a variable using output buffering and write to file. This file is then dished out to all subsequent hits for X number of minutes before it refreshes the file with a new HTML build. Its a basic inline cache builder tacked onto an older site code.

After witnessing a few issues of an empty page, I tracked it down that ob_get_contents() was returning nothing for a given refresh-run. When it would refresh the next time, it was usually ok. Then, out of the blue, empty return again hours later (never at the 'same time' either).

It is driving me mad, because it is not consistent. I have the php action email me when the return from ob_get_contents() is empty... with a bunch of details. Nothing seems to shed light 'why'.

After reducing the complex version of the code down to just its core... this is all that it is which causes the problem:

```
ob_start();

// A lot of html generation code which would normally just output ...
// This html will ALWAYS have content ...

$guts = ob_get_contents();
if ( empty($guts) ) { /* email me a failure notice! */ }
ob_end_clean();
// write $guts to file and echo ...
```

Some other details:

- PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.19 (maybe a bug in this version?)
- output_buffering  4096
- ob_get_level() always returns "2"
- HTML generation ranges from 10KB to 92KB depending on which piece
- Does not always occur on same HTML piece
- All have been hits that had no POST or GET args passed.
- The majority are these kind of agents (all random IPs):

  - "Ruby"
  - "Mo%20PTT/2016092702 CFNetwork/808.0.2 Darwin/16.0.0"
  - "FeedBurner/1.0"

**Please note:** It is not *always* returning empty like other stack questions about ob_get_contents(). I read those over, no help there... I wish it was always, then it would be an obvious fix.

Comment: Did you try it in other php versions like `5.6.25`?

Comment: Unfortunately not able too at this time. Its a production server and upgrades have to go through stages. The test server never exhibits this issue because it doesn't get enough traffic (just me hitting it a hundred times never causes the problem it seems).

Comment: There are several bugs in PHP v5.5.9, you can see here: http://php.net/releases/5_5_10.php, just check whats changed

Comment: Of course there are more updates v.5.5.11.. etc. if its possible update your php version to last stable version.

Comment: I'll propose it to our server guy thanks. Not sure why he chose this particular 5.5 though. Maybe baby steps since this server runs very very old code I am constantly updating.

Comment: I did do a full code search for other ob_* functions, and came up with none in the sequence. Given the HTML generation, I would think it always happen, instead of randomly/rarely. The only difference between one generation to the next, is different database information pulled to make it (clean data, nothing public supplied).

Comment: @RyanVincent I will do a more exhaustive search monday though, for other things that might tamper with output buffering other than the obvious ob_* functions.

Comment: After the IT guy updated the ubuntu, he said it will be 5.5.9 as he doesnt want to step outside what the kernal package installs or whatever. The update didn't fix the issue i'm seeing. And I have gone through all the html gen code and cannot find out why this randomly happens. I guess I will have to wait until the IT guy moves us to a ubuntu that comes with the php 5.6.x packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been witnessing a similar issue on the same PHP version (5.5.9) for months. Not able to switch to a different PHP version as well.
I have struggled to even detect this in our system, but fortunately was right now able to track down and exploit it.

In PHP 5.5.9 the function `print_r` internally uses output buffering, and there are bugs reported in this version regarding that `print_r` and output buffering.

So here's what you need to do..

### Create script first.php:

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(true);// (curl disconnects after 1 second)
ini_set('max_execution_time','180');    // 3 minutes
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');         // 512 MB

function testPrint_r($length)
{
    $test1 = array('TEST'=>'SOMETHING');
    $test2 = print_r($test1, true);
    $test3 = "Array\n(\n    [TEST] => SOMETHING\n)\n";
    if(strcmp($test2, $test3)!==0) {
        throw new Exception("Print_r check failed, output length so far: ".$length);
        // consult your error.log then, or use some other reporting means
    }
}

$message = "123456789\n";
$length = strlen($message);
while(1)
{
    echo $message;
    $total_length += $length;
    testPrint_r($total_length);
}
die('it should not get here');
```

### Create another script second.php:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,    'http://some.server/first.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo "all done";
```

### What is going on here:

The first script just outputs some characters in a loop. And it does it by echoing 10 characters with every iteration. If you just call this script, it will always timeout after the configured time.

The second script calls the first one with CURL, but in a disconnected way (1 second). That's why the first script contains ignore user abort.

Somehow, most probably due to some bug(s) specific to php version 5.5.9, after around 1.8MB of data was already echoed, print_r and so any additional output buffering usage breaks. Print_r with second parameter TRUE returns just nothing. Most probably some internal or system side buffer runs out, additional characters cannot be put anywhere, or the already echoed characters are dropped. Don't know. I was not able to find correlation between the threshold number and any config setting from phpinfo. Output buffering has no value set in our system.

### My recommendations

So it might be that some CURL/WGET was used and disconnected, or normal browser was used and disconnected just in the beginning. Names like "Ruby", "FeedBurner" sound like libs or robots to me.

a) If your script is not too complex, try avoiding output buffering in PHP 5.5.9, print_r as well. var_export is fine, works differently.

b) Replace echoes with string concatenation, direct to file writing, when generating output. If you use smarty, then this may not be possible, because smarty uses output buffering internally a lot.

c) Or create a list of banned agents, if they are the majority for these failures.

d) Btw. if your ob_get_level() returns 2, that means that the output buffering is in your system by default turned on. I think you do not need that for your task, turning that off may even help you. It's worth trying.

Try running the same scripts on your system and let me know what was the max.echoed size in your case.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back on this. I had put in precautions to prevent blank outputs, so then kind of gave up caring at this point to spend more time on it. But your information is very interesting, and insightful if this is the case. Unfortunately, I'm unable to really setup that test at the moment! Maybe if we revisit the problem, I will reference this again.

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved a similar problem by adding the line `php_flag output_buffering On` to my `.htaccess` file. In my case my PHP file contained first HTML code, then a PHP block that called the `ob_get_contents` command. Sometimes the result of this ob_get_contents was empty. I am not sure if this always works, or why.

Answer (score 0):

You could work around that problem having a cron job that rebuilds the file and saves it only on success, and the server serves only the static file. You will newer get the empty page that way.

Comment: I do have it not cache and display at that point, basically turning the page hit into a full-build hit, instead of a cache pull. I mean, that works... but I sure wish I could find the root cause of why it happens at all. Had to put that on hold though, due to other big projects *